# Separate attributes for edges in edge list?

Tags: graphviz

I can add edge labels with attributes like so

```
digraph structs {
  a -> x [label="A"];
  a -> y [label="B"];
}
```

and I can list all edges together

```
digraph structs {
  a -> {x; y;}; /* or a -> x,y; */
}
```

but from the DOT grammar it looks like I can only specify a single set of attributes for *all* edges in the list

```
digraph structs {
  a -> {x; y;} [label="D'oh!"];
}
```

Because of the way that my graph is generated, I'd love to have a way to write something like

```
digraph structs {
  a -> x [label="X"], y [label="Y"];
}
```

where the *edges* from a to x and y are labeled X and Y, respectively. Is that possible without resorting to separate statements for each edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
digraph structs {
  a -> {x [label="X"]; y [label="Y"];}
}
```

These are actually separate statements, but it's one-line and close to what you want.